# Google Docs Custom Menu Hotkey (accelerator key/character, like "F" for File menu, or "S" for Save)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am adding a custom menu to a spreadsheet and would like to use a hotkey to access the menu.  The Alt-F hotkey opens the File pulldown menu.  I would like to define Alt-B to activate my pulldown.  Is there a way to do this?  If so, can I then add hotkeys to the menu items?  Here is the code I am using to add the menu:

```
function onOpen() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var BoxwoodMenuItems = [{name : "Payments & Registeration Check-ins", functionName : "htmlRegistrationPayments"},
                       {name: "Assign Billets", functionName: "htmlAssignBillets"},
                       null, // Results in a line separator.
                       {name : "Get Remaining # of Allowed Sent Emails", functionName : "showRemainingEmails"},
                       ];
  sheet.addMenu("Boxwood", BoxwoodMenuItems);
};
```

Comment: custom menus can't currently be assigned a hotkey, but you may want to look at doing a Chrome extension that automatically hit the right arrow button 7 times when ever you hit Alt+F. that'll get you to the script menu

Comment: Thank you for the response. Too bad I can't assign a hotkey.

Comment: Or, when you hit alt+f, it then hits the key-command for the menu next/closest to the custom menu, then it likely only needs one or two right-button presses.

Comment: There should be accelerator keys for the menu itself, as well as each item in it. This plus the ability to assign key-commands to scripts would make things a lot faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom keyboard shortcuts for google app script functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions)

Answer (score 2):

At this time it's not possible to set custom keyboard shortcuts / hotkeys Google Docs / Sheets / Forms / Slides for custom menus, but it's possible to do that for [Google Sheets Macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros).

References

- Official Guides

  - [Custom Menus in G Suite](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- Official Issue Tracker

  - [Need a support to map shortcut to script functions](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36752620)

Answer (score 1):

`Alt-H` > `Right Arrow` > `Down Arrow` > `Enter` Works for me without macros ( one `Down Arrow` for the first custom menu item, two `Down Arrow` for second and so on.

(That is, Help menu on menubar selected, then your custom menu and then down for your custom functions.)