# Is it still impossible to create a shortcut for a user script in google docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have a script to formatting the selected text in Google document and I want to assign a shortcut to it. I get an impression that it's impossible, based on some incomplete/outdated info from Google search.

So, is it possible? or still impossible? Thanks.

Comment: Still impossible, and this is really a web app usage question, better suited for [webapps.se]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and the answer. Was not aware of the Web Application site...Just feel that Stack overflow has too many sites and time will be wasted to find the right site... Why it's not just an tag here?

Comment: why don't you just put it into a library with other useful scripts and load it whenever you need it.

Comment: @Cooper, sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you elaborate? Will it all me to call my script from a shortcut? Thanks.

Comment: You can put it on a menu.  I guess I'm not sure what you mean by a short cut.  If you had such a short cut would you be sitting at your computer with the Google Document open in front of you and think to yourself that I wish to run my format script and want to just  click a menu item on a drop down or a sidebar and execute a scripted function?  So the question is under what circumstances would you use this shortcut?

Comment: Hi @Cooper, actually I did manage to add it into a menu, but I want to make it even simpler: using keyboard shortcuts like CTRL+ALT+b. Is this possible?

Comment: Oh key board short cuts.  I don't think we can capture them except on dialogs or sidebars when they have focus.  You could put fairly large buttons on a sidebar and if you have a touchscreen that would be convenient.  I use side bars for projects that have a lot of work flow steps because they're quicker than drop down menus and with a touch screen you don't even need a mouse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Docs Custom Menu Hotkey (accelerator key/character, like "F" for File menu, or "S" for Save)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434257/google-docs-custom-menu-hotkey-accelerator-key-character-like-f-for-file-men)