# Change the color of all tables in google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, background-color, google-docs

I'm trying to change the color of all my tables in a google document using https://script.google.com.   Looking at the Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#setbackgroundcolorcolor), I found the setbackgroundcolor (color) method.

Another question, can I use the keyboard to execute the created functions ?.

Comment: Hello, can you please provide what you have tried and what doesn't work? Hard to assist without knowing your current code

Comment: @Vytautas Sorry, I have not created any code. I have been looking for and reading documentations and posts of other users.

Comment: Since you have 151 points already I did not feel the need to refer you to the [help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to ask questions on topic initially. Your question is something that can be found in documentation and attempting to write the code (seems to be quite a basic task). Your second question has also been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=306) (others reference that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think keyboard functionalities is fully supported as of now. Closest thing I can find is [Use add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) but nowhere does it explicitly mention keyboard support to execute functions. I think this is also confirmed in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions).