# I am trying to make a Google Docs add-on that uses custom keyboard shortcuts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-workspace

I am trying to make a Google Docs add-on that uses custom keyboard shortcuts to activate special features.  I can get the letter key codes to work, however, I need to use the [Ctrl] key but the javascript keycode "17" won't work.

Can anyone help me with this?  I have looked "everywhere" (A LOT of places) for how to get this to work but I just can't seem to find the right thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom keyboard shortcuts for google app script functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){ 
  //CTRL + V keydown combo 
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 86){ 
    $( '#output' ).html("I've been pressed!"); 
  } 
})
```

Comment: The full code to implement it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44345522/3154274)