# Using Google App Script to Open a Prompt or Dialog Box with Text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I am trying to set up an App Script add on for Google Sheets.

What I am hoping to do is allow the user to be in Google Sheets (with the focus on the current cell or selection of cells). Whenever the user hits "alt", it would either allow a prompt or dialog box to open up with text input. The user can then enter a short String, which would be a command that would get executed in Appscript based on what the command is. (akin to Excel hot keys).

Is there a way to do this in App Script today?

I have tried several links below but struggling to figure out how to do this.

I would ideally not have the user have to use the mouse for anything if possible (e.g., clicking on a dialog box).

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions/69711388#69711388)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342221/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-docs-change-color-background-color/44345522#44345522)

Comment: I don't think so.  You'll will have to call a function with either a menu or a button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions

Comment: @Kos -- thanks for sharing. That was one of the links I had posted about. It wasn't clear to me from those posts that I can do what I posted above, hence I posted my question.

Comment: Yeah no, so that post doesn't answer your question?

Comment: No, I believe not. I believe it links to some code that requires the creation of a dialog or sidebar that needs to be clicked on.

Comment: But you missed top rated answer there, I think it is pretty correct

Comment: There's macros(https://stackoverflow.com/a/49946187/), but not one button click -but ctrl+alt+<your button>

Comment: @Kos -- not sure I understand what you mean. I looked all over that post and nothing was helpful with respect to my specific request. Are you saying the post is pretty correct or what I wrote is correct?

Comment: @TheMaster -- I don't want to use a macro as they are not distributable in a Sheets Add On.

Comment: @srachoor If you've reviewed such answers, you should've explained why each answer is unsatisfactory - in your question itself. So that we don't have to waste time suggesting solutions that you already were aware of and of which you think it won't work.