# How call sheet menu item by using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

In a sheet script function, how can I run/activate a sheet menu item like find and replace function <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>?

Comment: What code have you come up with so far? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom keyboard shortcuts for google app script functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot bind a keystroke to a specific GAS function. The closest you can get to a keystroke is to call an AddOn function by using Option (Alt) + / and typing the AddOn name.