# Set Custom Tab Order using Apps Script for Custom Built Data Entry form in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a spreadsheet that has been styled to look like a data entry form. I'd like to set a custom "Tab Order" for this sheet so that when a user is entering data, each time the `TAB` key is pressed, the users active cell advances to the next entry point on the form. Anyone know how to kick this off? I'm assuming this is possible with Apps Script.

To clarify, I'm not looking for a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to run an Apps Script, I want to write a script that listens for the `TAB` key press and then, based on whichever cell is currently active in the entry form, I'd like the active cell to move to the next entry point, and so on.

Many thanks in advance,
Ryan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom keyboard shortcuts for google app script functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions)

Comment: @Cooper I think you're right. I've missed checking it. Upon double checking, the macros method only supports keyboard combinations like [`Ctrl +Shift + [any number from 0-9]`](https://imgur.com/a/fjRrmTV). This seems to be only a workaround, but the catch is user won't be able to use the `tab` key.