# Keyboard Shortcuts for Google Appscript scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way I can assign a key on my physical keyboard to run functions created in Appscripts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom keyboard shortcuts for google app script functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731589/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-app-script-functions)